# setting textarea to empty yet it reloads variable data on submission

Tags: php, html, textarea

If I set my text area in my edit page to blank and I hit submit, it reloads the page with an error as its supposed to but it also loads the summary text from my php variable. instead it should stay blank.

Here's what I've tried:

```php
<textarea name="summarytxt" cols="52" rows="7">
<?php
    if ( isset($_POST['updatebtn']) AND (!empty($POST['summarytxt']))  ){ 
        echo @$POST['summarytxt'];
    } 
    elseif ( isset($_POST['updatebtn']) AND (isset($POST['summarytxt']))  ){ 
        echo @$POST['summarytxt'];
    } 
    else{ 
        $summary=stripslashes($data['summary']);
        echo $summary;
    }
?>
</textarea>
```

I was hoping the elseif condition will fix it but it doesn't seem to work:

```
 elseif ( isset($_POST['updatebtn']) AND (isset($POST['summarytxt']))  )
```

The above to me meant if the button is clicked and the text area is set echo whatever is in the text area.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong or how I can fix it?

Edit:

I basically want to know the following:

if say i have field summarytxt and an array called data['summary'] i need:
1. on page load, load from data['summary']
2. if the user clears the summarytxt, on page submit, it should be blank inside summarytxt

i have tried the following which seems to work...

```
<?php
                if (!isset($_POST['updatebtn'])){
                    $summary=stripslashes($data['summary']);
                    echo $summary;      
                }else{
                    echo $_POST['summarytxt'];

                }
                ?>
```

Now i'm having some trouble with my drop down box:
1. when i change it from a product to 'select' which is what you get in the add form, and i update the page. instead of sticking to select its loading the product it had when i opened the form.

Can somebody please show me a simple way of this? thanks!

Comment: Why don`t you only check if the summarytxt is set and then echo it? That of course after checking that form was submitted like this: if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")

Comment: @greenhoodlum Its only supposed to echo if summarytext isnt empty?

Comment: @AlexanderNorway hi, if i delete the summarytxt and fail to fill in another field it should leave summarytxt empty and display an error for the field and summarytxt. but instead its echo's the text in variable.

Answer (score 1):

So I would do this similar to (remember about php and html separation):

```
<?php
$summary = "";
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $summary = stripslashes($_POST['summarytxt']);
}
?>
<textarea name="summarytxt" cols="52" rows="7"><?php echo $summary; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Hi thanks. that only partially works. If i delete everything in the summarytext and hit update, the summarytxt is empty (as it should be), the page reloads with the error. but if i fail to fill another required field and hit update, on page reload the summarytxt is blank (it deletes the text that was already in there).